# How to format this date

Tags: iphone, nsdateformatter

Hi I have a string that is like this: `Thu, 09 Jun 2011 5:00 pm CST`, where CST could be any time zone or something.

Help I tried this already but it's null:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter2 setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy h:mm z"];
[formatter2 setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]autorelease]];
[formatter2 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
NSDate *time = [formatter2 dateFromString:@"Thu, 09 Jun 2011 5:00 pm KST"];
[formatter2 release];
NSLog(@"%@",time); //null
```

Am I doing somethings wrong?  Help me I'm new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't accounting for the AM/PM.  I believe that that is `'a'`.

try:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter2 setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy h:mm a z"];
[formatter2 setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]autorelease]];
[formatter2 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
NSDate *time = [formatter2 dateFromString:@"Thu, 09 Jun 2011 5:00 pm KST"];
[formatter2 release];
NSLog(@"%@",time); //null
```